What does <type>.<attr> do during a match/case?
In general, the code <type>(arg1=value1) is changed to the code <type>(attr1=value1) during a case in a match statement. This allows for some very interesting and complex capturing.
For example, we can ask "does my instance have a attr called 'sort', if so capture it":
match [1,2,3]:
    case list(sort=f): # this isn't a call, it is an attr-capture statement
        print(f)

Since the first (and only) positional argument of the list instance is the list values, you can capture those items as well:
match [1,2,3]:
    case list((x,*y),sort=f): # here we are capturing the 'attr' called 'sort' as 'f'
        print(x,y,f)

Likewise, you can specify the matching values instead of capturing them into variables:
g = list.sort
match [1,2,3]:
    case list((1,*y),sort=g):  # here we ask if the attr 'sort' is the same as 'g'
        print(y)

However, I am now confused by the following:
match [1,2,3]:
    case list(x,sort=list.sort):  # fails to match, but why???
        print(x)

I would have thought that this fails because list.sort means something different than to specify "the function 'sort' of 'list'". Maybe sort=list.sort means "do I have an attr called 'sort' which itself is of 'type' 'list' that also has an attr called 'sort'". So I tried:
match [1,2,3]:
    case list.sort:  # also fails, why?
        print('ya')

So, list.sort does not mean that I want type list with an attr of sort. So, then I tried:
match list.sort:
    case list.sort: # does match, wait, what?
        print('ya')

Which works. So, list.sort during a case does mean to use the function of sort from the type of list, but then why did list(sort=list.sort) fail?

Example of capturing an attr 'y' and matching an attr 'x':
class P:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.x,self.y = a+b,a-b
match P(5,6):
    case P(x=11,y=a): # a is a new variable, 11 is a match
        print(a)


"here we ask if the attr 'sort' is the same as 'g'" - I don't think that's true, whatever g was before gets shadowed by the capture of the match's sort method.

list.sort is a function object.  It's never going to match a list object, but of course it can match itself.

@jonrsharpe but it doesn't overwrite for other attr values, the (1,...) in the tuple. you can check this for a custom class by setting an attr to say "7" and then specifying it instead of capturing it.

@TimRoberts right, but then why does the "list(sort=list.sort)" fail to capture?

How would you override the value of 1?! I don't see why you'd think that sort=f would capture the attribute sort of the match to f (correct, as your output demonstrates) but decide that sort=g does something completely different.

@jonrsharpe that is the way the documentation works. specifying something that already exists means to "match", specifying a new variable means "capture". I will add an example.

But you can demonstrate with e.g. g = "not the list.sort method" that after the match it's <built-in method sort ... again, even though [1, 2, 3].sort very much isn't that string. 11 isn't an existing variable, an identifier; it's a value. list.sort isn't an identifier, so it's treated as a value.

@jonrsharpe OMG, you can't use defined variables in a capture. I never realized that. What does that say about "list(sort=list.sort)"? What is it doing?

@jonrsharpe your saying that list.sort is treated as a value, but that doesn't appear to be the case, since "list(sort=list.sort)" does not match the instance [1,2,3] even though it's attr "sort" is in fact the "list.sort".

"it's attr "sort" is in fact the "list.sort"" - list.sort is <method 'sort' of 'list' objects>, not <built-in method sort of list object at 0x...>. If you factored out e.g. l = [1, 2, 3] and used list(sort=l.sort), the bound method of the same instance, you'd see it matched that case.

@jonsharpe i never knew that class methods are not the same methods as the instances, has that always been the case?

Please clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments. Comments are not for asking new questions. Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question, in your post. If you get something you don't expect when you give a [mre], say what you expected & why justified by authoritative documentation; otherwise you're just asking for documentation to be rewritten with no details on what you do or don't understand or misunderstand in it. [ask] [Help]

list.sort is a descriptor, so it's not going to match sort= which will be a method or function.
You can see the type of f is a built-in method:
match [1,2,3]:
    case list(x,*y), sort=f): # inspect the capture of `sort` as `f`
        print('match', f) # match <built-in method sort of list object at 0x104d94c80>

But the type of list.sort is not:
>>> type(list.sort)
method_descriptor
>>> list.sort is [1,2,3].sort
False

But if you use the method from the same list instance, this works:
foo = [1,2,3]
match foo:
    case list((x, *y), sort=foo.sort):
        print('matched')

But this doesn't make much sense to me to match on the sort attribute, as it's different for each instance of a list:
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> x.sort is y.sort
False
>>> x.sort == y.sort
False


thanks! i never realized that [1,2,3].sort is list.sort is false. i have always thought of instances calling methods as calling the methods i defined in the class, i never noticed that python separates them. has that always been the case?

list.sort is an ordinary function. [1,2,3].sort is a bound method (an instance of  types.MethodType that wraps both [1,2,3] and list.sort).

The other thing this should probably cover is the fundamental difference between sort=f (identifier -> binds the value) and sort=list.sort (not an identifier -> another layer of pattern).

In match-speak, f is a capture pattern, while list.sort is a value pattern.

@chepner ya but this appears to not be unique to list, it appears that in any class P: pass, then P.__init__ is P().__init__ is false.

There are unmatched parentheses in the second line of the first code snippet.

You could think of [1,2,3].sort kind-of like list.sort.__get__([1,2,3], list).

Bound methods have always been different objects for each instance. functions and static methods are different, though. In Python2 unbound methods were also different from functions. In Python3 unbound methods are simply functions. If you did this same check with a static method, it would actually work as expected, since staticmethods on the class are the same object as the static method on every instance.

The other element is understanding what happens when you use an identifier (e.g., f) in a match statement versus a location/value (name.name or "literal value"), but I think others covered that. For completeness and authoritative sourcing, from PEP 636: "a bare name with no dots) will be always interpreted as a capture pattern"

@sytech ya, I am starting to realize that. case matching is kindof like an advanced form of unpacking, eg [(x,y),z] = [(1,2),(3,4)] ; so that makes sense. it is probably why there is the "if" part of the code so that you can capture and then compare if needed.
